# How to globally mock axios cache interceptor

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs

I am running some integration tests on some react components and one of them imports an axios helper function that looks like:

```
// axios-helper.ts
import Axios from 'axios'
import { CacheAxiosResponse, setupCache } from 'axios-cache-interceptor'

export const xhr = setupCache(Axios.create({
  timeout: 90000
}))
```

I tried mocking this cache cause I don't want to test it using a `setupTests.js` like so:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
import { setupCache } from 'axios-cache-interceptor'


export const mockCache = {
  get: jest.fn(),
  set: jest.fn(),
  reset: jest.fn()
}

setupCache.mockReturnValue(mockCache)
```

But then I get the following error when running any test suite that imports that caching function:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mockReturnValue')

      15 | }
      16 |
    > 17 | setupCache.mockReturnValue(mockCache)
         |            ^
      18 |
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `setupCache` is not a part of the default export, you can`t directly mock it this way.

Instead, you can import the entire module and then mock the `setupCache` function of that module.

```js
jest.mock('axios-cache-interceptor', () => ({
  setupCache: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockCache),
}));
```

Comment: I still get the same error. I added your jest.mock at the top of my specific component test but my original `setupTest.js` is still throwing the same issue.

Comment: Do you want to mock setupCache for specific component test or globally for all? As far as I tested mocking of this function and it seemed to work fine

Comment: If you want to mock it only in specific test, how can setupTest throw this error if there is not reference to it? Probably I don't completely understand the point. Can you provide a bit more code?